# Java (or Scala) want to reload yaml configs during runtime

Tags: java, scala

**My problem:**
I am writing a scala application that requires me to check for file changes in a yaml file and if any, reload that yaml file.

I've researched quite a bit and have only found [commons-configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_reloading.html) that can be used to reload java properties file and some other watcher services that reloads the same (properties files).

Is there anything out there I can use to auto-reload configs yaml files? Can be Java or Scala.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the [Watcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to check for any file changes and used SnakeYaml to load the yaml file again.